# Rails pages not showing even though passenger is running

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, capistrano, passenger, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy my first proper Rails Project.
I have a Ubuntu 12.04 virtual server with Nginx, Passenger and PostgreSQL installed.
I have deployed the code to the server using Capistrano.

Everything should be working but for some reason when trying to access the pages through the browser, it just tries to connect for about 10 seconds and then times out.
However, all static pages, such as address/500.html and address/robots.txt load correctly.

I have checked the Nginx error logs at /opt/nginx/logs but they are empty. The Nginx access log on the other hand only logs some of my attempts.
Nginx access log:

```
130.233.194.3 - - [18/Sep/2012:11:13:04 +0300] "GET /somestuff HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
130.233.194.3 - - [18/Sep/2012:11:37:59 +0300] "GET /500.html HTTP/1.1" 200 643
"-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
130.233.194.3 - - [18/Sep/2012:11:45:59 +0300] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
130.233.194.3 - - [18/Sep/2012:11:57:32 +0300] "GET /500.html HTTP/1.1" 200 643
"-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
130.233.194.3 - - [18/Sep/2012:11:57:47 +0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
130.233.194.3 - - [18/Sep/2012:11:58:19 +0300] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 204 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
```

(For instance, right after the /somestuff, I tried /nopage, but it isn't logged)

My Rails App production log only shows the database migrations. I can also open the Rails console in production mode and write things into database so I don't think that is the problem.

If I write "app.get("/")" or any other page in the rails console, it will only return 301
(Don't know if that is relevant, on my development enviroment it returns 200)

Here are some other files that might be relevant:

nginx.conf:

```
#user  [User used in deploying];
   server {
        listen 80;
        server_name [Name_of_the_server];
        root /home/[User used in deploying]/srv/nsbg/current/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
}
```

(That's what I have added, otherwise it's default)

Capistrano deploy file:

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
set :user, '[User used in deploying]'
set :domain, '[server name]'
set :applicationdir, "/home/[User used in deploying]/srv/nsbg"

set :scm, 'git'
set :repository,  "[Github repo]"
set :git_enable_submodules, 1 # if you have vendored rails
set :branch, 'master'
set :git_shallow_clone, 1
set :scm_verbose, true

# roles (servers)
role :web, domain
role :app, domain
role :db,  domain, :primary => true

# deploy config
set :deploy_to, applicationdir
set :deploy_via, :export

# additional settings
default_run_options[:pty] = true  # Forgo errors when deploying from windows
#ssh_options[:keys] = %w(/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa)            # If you are using ssh_keysset :chmod755, "app config db lib public vendor script script/* public/disp*"set :use_sudo, false

# Passenger
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

Using command "sudo passenger-status":

```
----------- General information -----------
max      = 6
count    = 1
active   = 0
inactive = 1
Waiting on global queue: 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/home/[User used in deploying]/srv/nsbg/current:
  App root: /home/[User used in deploying]/srv/nsbg/current
  * PID: 8038    Sessions: 0    Processed: 1       Uptime: 1h 4m 29s
```

Like I said, static pages get served but any other page (including invalid routes) simply hang up and no error is written anywhere.
Please help me, I am very unexperienced in deploying and completely lost

Comment: Is Postgres running? Does the `database.yml` correctly find the database? 500 errors sitewide are often caused by a missing database.

Comment: Well, it should be, because if I open the production rails console, I can call the database from there and it doesn't give any errors. I only have the production database set up but shouldn't passenger default to production mode?

Comment: Yes, that would indicate that the db is fine. Thanks for checking and clarifying.